# How can I prevent Parental Controls from repeatedly popping up?

Tags: user-account, parental-controls

Problems I have are following with parental controls (on children account):

If I limit applications, some applications that run on startup are constantly popping up, it does not matter if I click ok and do not enter password, they keep popping out until I allow them to work (applications that I personally use like Teamviwer, Brother printer software and so on, no malware).

How to stop it? I understood that if I do not allow something, that will not work. Maybe ask me one time or twice but not constantly popping out so my children cannot play games.

Comment: You had several questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your other questions, but feel free to ask them separately.

Comment: Thank you but I think that now when you edited it, I will never get answer to this one also :D

Comment: Feel free to edit it into shape if you think it should be worded differently.